Extracting face outline from a facial bounding box with the iOS vision framework
I'm trying to crop a full face outline (i.e face contour points + eye brow points only) from facial landmarks obtained from VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest. I'm facing a problem translating normalized face contour points as returned by the iOS vision framework into image coordinates.
I'm using VNImagePointForFaceLandmarkPoint() to convert each facial contour point to an image coordinate but the face outline is still misaligned. I've tried manually translating the points but still failed.
The output image i.e. image with misaligned facial contour (red dots) of the following function is attached at the end of post.
Click here to see the how points for the facial contour are expected.
func faceRecognitionNormalisationPhase(faceObservation: VNFaceObservation, uiImage: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(uiImage.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    uiImage.draw(at: .zero)
    context?.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
    context?.setStrokeColor((UIColor.red.cgColor))
    
    // Get the face contour points
    guard let faceContour = faceObservation.landmarks?.faceContour else {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return uiImage
    }
    print("facecontour: \(faceContour.normalizedPoints)")
    let imageSize = uiImage.size
    let boundingBox = faceObservation.boundingBox
    
    for i in 0..<faceContour.pointCount {
        // gets normalized points
        let point = faceContour.normalizedPoints[i]
        let imagePoint = VNImagePointForFaceLandmarkPoint(vector_float2(Float(point.x), Float(point.y)), boundingBox, Int(imageSize.width), Int(imageSize.height))
        print("Normalized point: \(point), Scaled point: \(CGFloat(imagePoint.x)), \(CGFloat(imagePoint.y))")
        let pointRect = CGRect(x: CGFloat(imagePoint.x) - 5, y: CGFloat(imagePoint.y) - 5, width: 10, height: 10)
        context?.fillEllipse(in: pointRect)
    }

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage!, nil, nil, nil)
    return newImage!
}



What device and iOS version are you running this on?

iPhone 14 pro simulator with iOS 16.2 @DonMag

This question is similar to: Wrong Vision Framework Landmarks Coordinates. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@riser101 - it's very possible that Vision on Simulator is not reliable. Try it on an actual device.

Thanks for your inputs. I had looked into that answer previously. My macbook does not support macOS > 12 which is required for running Xcode 15, which in turn is required to run apps on iOS 17. In short, Xcode 14 (at least Xcode 15 is required) cannot run apps on iOS 17 devices. I'll find a way and update this question accordingly
